# Rails editing an Image attached to a model

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm trying to set up a model (client) that contains some general attributes about a company but also has a company logo attached. I'm reluctant to use a plugin because I want to grasp this aspect of rails if possible.

I've created a clients model and an image model and I can create a new client (scaffold code) and upload an accompanying image ok (using `has_one :image`, and `belongs_to :client`).

I used the following code (taken straight from Agile Rails 3rd ed)

```
class Client < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :image

  def uploaded_image=(image_file)
    self.image = Image.new
    self.image.name = base_part_of(image_file.original_filename)
    self.image.content_type = image_file.content_type
    self.image.data = image_file.read
  end

  def base_part_of(filename)
    File.basename(filename).gsub(/^\w_-/,'')
  end

end
```

when **editing** the client object however, the new file is uploaded but the changes aren't reflected in the db. Do I need to explicitly call update-attributes on @client.image? At the moment my controller update method is as follows:

```
def update
  @client = Client.find(params[:id])

  respond_to do |format|
    if @client.update_attributes(params[:client])
      flash[:notice] = 'Client was successfully updated.'
      format.html { redirect_to(@client) }
      format.xml  { head :ok }
    else
      format.html { render :action => "edit" }
      format.xml  { render :xml => @client.errors, :status => :unprocessable_entity }
    end
  end
end
```

Thanks in advance for any tips, apologies for the noob question

Comment: Please show view for new and edit actions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would strongly recommend to use [Paperclip](http://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip) instead. It just works.

Comment: Or at least have a look at the Paperclip source.

Comment: Ok thanks for the tip, I have it working using a separate update action but it's not as clean as some paperclip code I've seen in tutorials. Yep i'll have a look at the Paperclip source too, thanks Toby